# How to fix "End of HDF5 error back trace Unable to open/create file"

Tags: pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

i try to open a h5 file and it give me an error and cannot read it. I show here the code which really basic, and the file i located it in the same directory I'm working on. This is the code:

I already updated pandas, pytables, pathlib
I tried with h5py.File

```
store = pd.HDFStore(path_to_file)
   df = store['data']
   store.close()
```

This is the error:

File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 492, in   tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new

HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace
...

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file

I hope you can help me
Many thanks!

Comment: I am having a similar error. If I change the file name, I am able to save. But when I delete the file and try to save again, it gives me 'unable to open/create file' error. I am saving on a remove server. Doesn't happen when I save locally in my hard disk. Also doesn't happen when I save as csv. Does changing the file name help?